# Al carga un archivo JSON solo me muestra 42 datos de 625 que tiene el archivo

Tags: python-3.x, json, lista

Al ejecutar el siguiente código se carga sin ningún error el archivo json, pero al imprimirlo solo muestra 42 registros de 625 que tiene el archivo original y al final solo aparece la leyenda 'detalle': []}, como lo muestro al final. ¿quiero lograr obtener todas las urls del archivo y no solo las 40 que muestra.

```
import pandas as pd 
import json 
import csv
with open ('recetas_request_2.json') as file:
    data_json=json.load(file)
print(data_json)
```

> {'c': 34340, 'chefnombre': 'Neurobion  ', 'f': 2, 'imagen': '39930.jpg', 'nombre': 'Gratín de Calabacitas a la Mexicana', 'p': 'normal', 'prating': '100.0%', 'rating': '5.0', 'ruta': '/receta/guarniciones/verduras/calabacitas/gratin-de-calabacitas-a-la-mexicana', 't': 'receta', 'v': '6031469592001', 'vh': '100.00%', 'vp': 'B1xDbuGM', 'x': 'p|kiwi|recetaclasificacion|2004|1|0|35'}, {'c': 34176, 'chefnombre': 'Brenda Villagomez', 'f': 2, 'imagen': '39792.jpg', 'nombre': 'Tinga de Res Fácil', 'p': 'normal', 'prating': '98.0%', 'rating': '4.9', 'ruta': '/receta/carnes-y-aves/res/guisados-de-carne/tinga-de-res-facil', 't': 'receta', 'v': '6026892108001', 'vh': '100.00%', 'vp': 'B1xDbuGM', 'x': 'p|kiwi|recetaclasificacion|2004|1|0|36'}], 'detalle': []}

Comment: Veo que es un solo objeto con muchas propiedades: ¿ No tendrá algunas propiedades con el mismo nombre pero distinto valor ?

Comment: No, todos los objetos tiene exactamente la misma forma, pero se detiene en el 42.

Comment: Hola Abraham, ¿Sería posible que compartieras el JSON completo para poder reproducir el problema? Si es demasiado para agregarlo a la pregunta puedes subirlo a Gogle Drive, MS OneDrive o similar. Es extraño, el resultado que muestras ni siquiera es un diccionario válido, sobran el "}]" que hay antes de la clave "detalle"....

Comment: aqui esta el json https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IWjwyfYB0-6wuvIJsHANt1suYY_7sKMh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hola Abraham, en el archivo hay 48 recetas incluidas en la clave "recetas", `data_json["recetas"]`. Se parsean todas sin problemas, pero no hay 625. Tal vez el problema sea a la hora de obtener el JSON del servidor, del scraping, etc, pero el JSON y su lectura son correctas.

Comment: Valida el Json, me sale que tiene un error.